# How to keep only unique object in an array of objects using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, lodash

I am getting the Response from the server like this

```
{
    owners:[
    {
    _id:"33333"
    email:test1@gmail.com
    }
    {
    _id:"1111"
    email:test2@gmail.com
    }]
    employee:[
     {
    _id:"44342"
    email:test1@gmail.com
    }
    {
    _id:"35345"
    email:test3@gmail.com
    }
     {
    _id:"3556"
    email:test4@gmail.com
    }
    ]
    users:[
    {
    _id:"56744"
    email:test5@gmail.com
    }
    {
    _id:"8908"
    email:test4@gmail.com
    }]
}
```

i want keep the objects Which are only having unique **email** id in all the array of objects the Result should be like this:

```
{
    owners:[
    {
    _id:"33333"
    email:test1@gmail.com
    }
    {
    _id:"1111"
    email:test2@gmail.com
    }]
    employee:[

    {
    _id:"35345"
    email:test3@gmail.com
    }
     {
    _id:"35345"
    email:test4@gmail.com
    }
    ]
    users:[
    {
    _id:"56744"
    email:test5@gmail.com
    }
]
}
```

can anybody help me on this Please.

Comment: Which of the duplicate records do you want to preserve, the first one? Because the _id's are unique and that inof will be lost forever.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want uniqueness across two array, you have to combine them first.

```
let combined = result.owners.map(o => {o.type = 'owner'; return o;})
            .concat(result.users.map(u => {u.type = 'user'; return u;});
combined = _.uniqBy(combined, 'email');

result.owners = _.filter(combined, {type: 'owner');
result.users = _.filter(combined, {type: 'user');
```

same thing with employees.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a few ways of doing this. One of the easiest would be using libraries like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#uniq) or [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) and using the `uniq` method to filter out duplicate objects on the basis of a property.

Using underscore as an example to get a unique list of owner objects:

`_.uniq(owners, 'email')`

Or a function of this sort would also work:

```
function uniqeValues(objects, property) {
     let unique_values = {};

     objects.forEach(object=> {
         if (!unique_values.hasOwnProperty(object[property])) {
             unique_values[object[property]] = object;
         }
     });

     return Object.values(unique_values);
}
```